# Why is a different instance of map updated after returning from callback in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why is a new instance of days created here after every call to DayofWeekInkWellButn? Works if i change days to static but that is not what i am looking for as it will create only one copy for every instance of ChoseDayRowWidget? Can someone please explain to me why is this happening and what can i do to solve this?

```
class ChoseDayRowWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  var days = {
    'Sunday': true,
    'Monday': true,
    'Tuesday': true,
    'Wednesday': true,
    'Thursday': true,
    'Friday': true,
    'Saturday': true
  };

  final DaysCallback callback;

  ChoseDayRowWidget({this.callback});

  @override
  _ChoseDayRowWidgetState createState() => _ChoseDayRowWidgetState();
}

class _ChoseDayRowWidgetState extends State<ChoseDayRowWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 7,
            vertical: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 3),
        child: DecoratedBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border:
              Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12, width: 1.3)),
            ),
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(Constants.GENERAL_CHOOSE_DAY_WIDGET_MESSAGE,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 3.5,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: CommonColorPallete.widgetTitleColor)),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 2,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  DayofWeekInkWellButn('S',widget.days['Sunday'],
                      callback: (val) => saveDays(val, 'Sunday')),
                  DayofWeekInkWellButn('M',widget.days['Monday'],
                      callback: (val) => saveDays(val, 'Monday')),
                  DayofWeekInkWellButn('T',widget.days['Tuesday'],
                      callback: (val) => saveDays(val, 'Tuesday')),
                  DayofWeekInkWellButn('W',widget.days['Wednesday'],
                      callback: (val) => saveDays(val, 'Wednesday')),
                  DayofWeekInkWellButn('T',widget.days['Thursday'],
                      callback: (val) => saveDays(val, 'Thursday')),
                  DayofWeekInkWellButn('F',widget.days['Friday'],
                      callback: (val) => saveDays(val, 'Friday')),
                  DayofWeekInkWellButn('S',widget.days['Saturday'],
                      callback: (val) => saveDays(val, 'Saturday')),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 3,
              )
            ])));
  }

  void saveDays(val, day) {
    setState(() {
      widget.days[day] = val;
      //widget.callback(widget.days);
    });

  }
}



typedef void DaysCallback(val);

class DayofWeekInkWellButn extends StatefulWidget {
  String day;
  final DaysCallback callback;
  bool flag;

  DayofWeekInkWellButn(this.day, this.flag, {this.callback});

  @override
  _DayofWeekInkWellButnState createState() => _DayofWeekInkWellButnState();
}


class _DayofWeekInkWellButnState extends State<DayofWeekInkWellButn> {
  bool flag = true;
  Color setColor = Colors.white;
  Color onSelectedFillColor = CommonColorPallete.onSelectedFillColor;
  Color onDeselectFillColor = CommonColorPallete.chooseDayOnDeselectFillColor;
  Color boundaryColor = CommonColorPallete.chooseDayBoundaryColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (flag == true) {
            setColor = onSelectedFillColor;
            boundaryColor = Colors.transparent;
          } else {
            boundaryColor = Colors.black;
            setColor = onDeselectFillColor;
          }
          flag = !flag;
          widget.callback(!flag);

        });
      },
      child: new Container(
        width: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5.5,
        height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5.5,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: setColor,
          border: new Border.all(color: boundaryColor, width: 1.0),
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        child: new Center(
          child: new Text(
            widget.day,
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 3.3,
                color: CommonColorPallete.fontColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A new instance is not beeing created every time. The problem is that your widget is a StatelessWidget. These type of widget don't allow you to mutate their data. If you want to mutate the content of the var days you must consider creating a StatefulWidget. Don't forget to call setState when you mutate the data so the ui can be rebuilt

Comment: i tried what you are saying but only the last DayofWeekInkWellButn clicked data is being saved in days, and the rest are being overwritten by the initialized values .

Comment: Can you update the code with your changes so we can see? And show us the code of DayofWeekInkWellButn too

Comment: I guess the logic is a little bit wrong. You are running the callback before toggling the flag so the setState is executed always with the same value

Comment: Now you are toggling two times. You are toggling the var and after you are toggling againg with the !